# What is the villager breed rate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the breed rate for villagers. I know the requirements of housing and the like. What I want to know is: is it like cattle, one breed every five minutes and twenty minutes to grow up? If so, are those the rates?

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no predefined amount of time you wait for villagers to breed. It is random, but depending on how many villagers you have, you could see them breeding at a fairly quick rate (even as fast as one every 2-5 minutes).

Comment: Ok, but there's still an expected rate (probabilistic definition of expected). If I'm going to wait for 5-10 villagers to breed probabilistic rates are all I care about anyway.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, and a duplicate of a question which has better answers already: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307463/is-there-a-cool-down-for-villager-breeding

Answer (score -3):

> Villagers will mate depending on available housing. The amount of housing can be supplemented by the player placing wooden doors nearby. To allow Minecraft to recognize the doors as houses, there needs to be a difference in the amount of blocks that can "see the sky" (i.e., have only [Air] or transparent blocks above them), counting five blocks in each direction (depending on the direction the door was placed). A house is initiated by a nearby villager (up to 16 blocks away horizontally along both axis, and up to 4 blocks vertically), and then either added to an existing or a new village. Sometimes the Villager AI doesn't behave as expected until the game is restarted.

[Minecraft Wiki - Villager Mating](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Mating_and_population)

So basically it's based on the amount of doors/building you have in your village.

Comment: No, that determines how much population you will get, not how quickly you will get there.

Comment: In the third paragraph of the wiki link, it states: *"The game engine periodically takes a census"*, but it does not state how often periodically happens.